# Pre-registered app "Azure Kubernetes Service AAD Server" not generated with AKS managed AAD integrated cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-active-directory, azure-aks

I am creating an AKS cluster having Azure managed integration with Azure Active Directory as mentioned in product docs -
[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/managed-aad)

As per the documentation, a pre-registered app with the name "Azure Kubernetes Service AAD Server" should get created in App Registration. But it is not getting created in my case.

Command used to create cluster :

```
az aks create -g myGroup -n myCLusterName --enable-aad --aad-admin-group-object-ids myAADGroupId
```

What could be the issue here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Azure Kubernetes Service AAD Server"* is a **`service principal`** that can be found in **Enterprise Applications** tab, not in App
> Registrations.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I don't have *"Azure Kubernetes Service AAD Server"* service principal in my **Enterprise Applications** before creating cluster.

[image]

Now I created one **cluster** by running ***same command*** as you like below:

```bash
az aks create -g myGroup -n myCLusterName --generate-ssh-keys --enable-aad --aad-admin-group-object-ids myAADGroupId
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked **Enterprise Applications** now, I can see *"Azure Kubernetes Service AAD Server"* service principal like below:

[image]

Make sure to **remove filters** while searching for service principal in Enterprise Applications.

Comment: Yes, after removing the existing filters the application becomes visible.

Answer (score 0):

From CLI, I was able to extract the application -

az ad sp list --display-name "Azure Kubernetes Service AAD Server"